# I am trying to select an image from a box and then click on the aligning button using selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the code for the image I uploaded

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body " data-id="textarea-WYSIWYG" contenteditable="true"><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p><a href="//www.shahidpro.tv/uploads/articles/60011c78.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[phpmelody]"><img src="//www.shahidpro.tv/uploads/articles/60011c78.jpg" width="500" height="500" vspace="" hspace="" border="0" alt=""></a></p></body>
  <p><a href="//www.shahidpro.tv/uploads/articles/60011c78.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[phpmelody]"><img src="//www.shahidpro.tv/uploads/articles/60011c78.jpg" width="500" height="500" vspace="" hspace="" border="0" alt=""></a></p>
```

I tried using

```
clk = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/p[2]/a"]'))).click()
```

and

```
clk = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tinymce"]/p[2]/a'))).click
```

and by partial link text using (//www.shahidpro.tv/uploads/articles/) but It doesn't click nor give error. I am pretty new to selenium and python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`.invisibility_of_element_located`**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located):

> An Expectation for checking that an element is either invisible or not present on the DOM.
> locator used to find the element

The question is why do you want to wait for the element to disappear then click?

Maybe what you need is [**`.visibility_of_element_located`**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located) or more precisely is [**`.element_to_be_clickable`**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable)